# Computation of Hilbert polynomial of two incident lines with nilpotent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

It is well known that the ideal $$I=(z^2,yz,xz,y^2-x^2(x+1))$$
occurs in a flat family of twisted cubic, so its Hilbert polynomial is $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^1}(3t))=3t+1$. The support of the ideal is a plane nodal cubic, and it has a nilpotent element at the singular point.

My question is about the ideal of this form:

1. Does the ideal $J=(z^2,yz,xz,y^2-x^2)$ defines two lines with a nilpotent at $0$?
2. How to compute the Hilbert polynomial of this ideal? (I suspect it is $2t+2$ for some reason but I don't know how to prove this.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. Set-theoretically, $V(J)=V(\sqrt{J})=V(z,yz,xz,y^2-x^2)=V(z,y^2-x^2)$ which is indeed two lines: $V(z,x-y)$ and $V(z,x+y)$. On $D(x)\cap V(J)$, we have that $x$ is invertible, so $z\in J_x$ and therefore $V(J)\cap D(x)$ is reduced. In the local ring at the origin, none of $x,y,z$ are invertible, so $z\notin \mathcal{O}_{V(J),(0,0,0)}$ and $V(J)$ isn't reduced there.
2. If you want a low-tech solution, you can just compute a bunch of terms of the quotient and use that Hilbert polynomials play nicely with exact sequences:

   - $\deg 0: \{1\}, \dim 1$
   - $\deg 1: \{x,y,z\}, \dim 3$
   - $\deg 2: \{x^2,xy\}, \dim 2$
   - $\deg 3: \{x^3,x^2y\}, \dim 2$
   - $\deg 4: \{x^4,x^3y\}, \dim 2$
   - $\deg 5$ and up will be dimension 2 as well: $x^n$ and $x^{n-1}y$ survive in the quotient, but nothing else does - nothing with a $z$ for obvious reasons, and then every monomial $x^ay^b$ is equivalent to either $x^n$ or $x^{n-1}y$ by turning $y^2$ in to $x^2$ a bunch.

So $H_J(t)+2=H_{k[x,y,z]}(t)$, or $H_j(t)=\binom{n+2}{2}-2=\frac{n^2+3n-1}{2}$.
If you want to use a bit more technology, you can do the same thing except note that the projective zero locus of $J$ inside $\Bbb P^2$ is two reduced points, which has Hilbert polynomial 2 and then apply the same exact sequence argument.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that, the ideal $I$ and $J$ in $k[x,y,z]$ are the localizations of homogeneous ideals in $\mathbb P^3$. So they are really ideal sheaves of curves, therefore the Hilbert polynomials should have degree one.

Comment: @AGlearner nontrivial ideals of $k[t_0,\cdots,t_n]$ have Hilbert polynomials that are degree $n$. You would be correct to say that $k[t_0,\cdots,t_n]/I$ has a Hilbert polynomial degree $1$ if $I$ is a homogeneous ideal of a curve in $\Bbb P^n$.

Comment: Yes, that's a correct way to put. I think one can end up computing the Hilbert polynomial of the quotient $k[w,x,y,z]/\bar{J}$ by computing the Hilbert polynomial on $J$. Could you explain in answer 2, what it means for the exact sequence in each degree? Also, you find a degree 2 polynomial, shouldn't we find a degree 3 polynomial?

Comment: If you have an exact sequence of graded modules $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, you get an exact sequence in each degree: $0\to A_d\to B_d\to C_d\to 0$. Since the Hilbert polynomial $H_M(d)$ eventually agrees with $\dim M_d$ for any graded module $M$, we have that $H_A(d)-H_B(d)+H_c(d)=0$ for all big enough $d$, so $H_A+H_C=H_B$ and that's what I'm using there. If you're confused about the degree, it might be helpful to look at the indexing again: the variables $t_i$ are $0$-indexed in the last comment.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what you are computing is $H_{k[x,y,z]/J}(t)$. Since $H_{k[x,y,z]/J}(d)=2$ for $d>>0$, it is the constant polynomial $2$. What I want to compute is $p(t)=H_{k[w,x,y,z]/(z^2,yz,xz,y^2-x^2)}(t)$, but it is not too far away, because $p(d)$ is counting the number of minomials $\{w^d,w^{d-1}x,w^{d-1}y,w^{d-1}z,w^{d-2}x^2,w^{d-2}xy,...,wx^{d-1},wx^{d-2}y,x^{d},x^{d-1}y\}$ which is $4+(d-1)\times 2=2d+2$, which is exactly what I want.